# Cypress test: HTTP error 414 - Request URL too long when Microsoft login, and page load timeout

Tags: cypress

This is my file:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress"/>

describe('Login to PortalCX', () => {
  it('sign up to MS', () => {
    cy.visit('https://login.microsoftonline.com/')
  })

})
```

And this is result [image]